# Byte[] Array to write/read to/from a Json file in C#

Tags: json, arrays, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, postman

I need to save the `byte[]` into `Json` file and read it when required in C#. The code which I used to implement that is:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("path", byteArrayObj);
```

When I check the file it's saving in String format. Is this the correct way of saving byte[] into a file? Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

I also has one more question. I am getting this `byte[]` as a parameter to one of my Web Api method.I am using `SwaggerUI` and `Postman Chrome Extension` for calling the Web API methods. Can anyone tell how to pass byte[] as a parameter in `SwaggerUI` and `Postman Chrome Extension`?